# Invoke the steps of waterfall of first dialog into other dialog by skipping the first step of a first dialog in bot framework v4

Tags: c#, dialog, frameworks, bots, robotframework

I have 3 dialogs in my bot framework v4 C# project, having waterfall steps in each.

In my second dialog have to behave the same as the first dialog but it doesn't have to execute all the steps of the first dialog, which means I need to skip the first step.

So is there any method to invoke all the waterfall steps of the first dialog into the other dialog by skipping the first step of the first dialog.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what exactly your second dialog is doing? I mean, are there any more waterfall steps in 2nd dialog. And, is it based on some condition that you want to invoke the first dialog from 2nd dialog or will it happen always? I might help you out with this, if you explain your problem more elaborately.

Comment: Also, do you want the second dialog to end right there when it calls the first dialog or you want to continue it further? Share a sample code in your question, if possible.

Comment: my first dialog has waterfall step , that need to be same in my second second dialog but first few steps of both dialog will be different, i just want that after the excuting the first few steps of of 2nd dialog it goes into the first dialog and skip  first step of that dialog and then excute every thing same as first dialog functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `waterfall` once formed is supposed to be executed in a step-by-step fashion. However, you can do the formation of your `waterfall steps` conditionally.

The condition here can be based on `DialogId`.

It's quite difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to do so, I've formed a sample solution for you. Hope you're trying to do the same.

Please refer the below code for the same :

MainDialog.cs

```
    namespace EchoBot.Dialogs
    {
        public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
        {
            private readonly BotStateService _botStateService;

            public MainDialog(BotStateService botStateService) : base(nameof(MainDialog))
            {
                _botStateService = botStateService;

                InitializeWaterfallDialog();
            }

            private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
            {
                var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
                {
                    InitialStepAsync,
                    FinalStepAsync
                };

                AddDialog(new SecondDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.second", _botStateService));
                AddDialog(new FirstDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.first", _botStateService)); 
AddDialog(new FirstDialog($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.firstFromSecond", _botStateService));
                AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallSteps));

                InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow";
            }

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if (Regex.Match(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text.ToLower(), "hi").Success)
                {
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.second", null, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.first", null, cancellationToken);
                }

            }

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
               return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null,cancellationToken);
            }
        } }
```

FirstDialog.cs

```
    namespace EchoBot.Dialogs
{
    public class FirstDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly BotStateService _botStateService;

        public FirstDialog(string dialogId, BotStateService botStateService) : base(dialogId)
        {
            _botStateService = botStateService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(botStateService));
            if (dialogId == $"{ nameof(MainDialog)}.first")
                InitializeWaterfallDialog1();
            else
                InitializeWaterfallDialog2();
        }

        private void InitializeWaterfallDialog1()
        {
            var waterfallsteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                GetAge,
                GetCity,
                FinalStepAsync
            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallsteps));
            AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.age"));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.city"));

            InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.mainFlow";
        }
        private void InitializeWaterfallDialog2()
        {
            var waterfallsteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                GetCity,
                FinalStepAsync
            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallsteps));
            AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.age"));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.city"));

            InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.mainFlow";
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetAge(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.age",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your age."),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter a valid age.")
                }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetCity(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(FirstDialog)}.age",
                 new PromptOptions
                 {
                     Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your city."),
                     RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter a valid city.")
                 }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }}
```

SecondDialog.cs

```
    namespace EchoBot.Dialogs
{
    public class SecondDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly BotStateService _botStateService;

        public SecondDialog(string dialogId, BotStateService botStateService) : base(dialogId) 
        {
            _botStateService = botStateService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(botStateService));

            InitializeWaterfallDialog();
        }

        private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
        {
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                InitialStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync
            };

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.name"));


            InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.mainFlow";
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.name",
                    new PromptOptions
                    {
                        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your Name.")
                    }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            //Suppose you want to call First Dialog from here
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.firstFromSecond", null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Added one line - `AddDialog(new FirstDialog($"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.firstFromSecond", _botStateService));` in `MainDialog.cs`. It's working fine for me.

Image 1 : When you go into second dialog from Main Dialog, it asks name and then skips first step of First Dialog (ie. age) and asks the second step ie. city.

[image: From Second Dialog]

Image 2 : When you go directly into first dialog from Main Dialog, it asks age and city both ie. it didn't skip first step.

[image: Directly First Dialog]

Hope this is helpful. Ask in comments if you have any query!

Comment: my project have few common steps that is written in my main dialog , and my other dialog has first two waterfall step different after that all waterfall step are same as in main dialog except the first step of main dialog , i don't want to write same waterfall step again in second dialog, instead that i want that after eexcuteing the first two waterfall step of second dialog, it goes to main dialog skip its first step and than excute all the waterfall steps of main dialog

Comment: `MainDialog` is an initial starting point. It is initialized as soon as the bot starts since it is injected from Bot Services ie. it's waterfall steps would be formed then and there itself. MainDialog in turn initializes First and Second Dialog. So from within the main dialog, you can intialize first dialog with two IDs. When you call it from the second dialog, call using a different ID, so it will implement it from waterfall step 2.

Comment: I've added a few images. Check out the code once, you'll understand what's going on. Focus on `MainDialog` - AddDialog steps, and how `FirstDialog` is being called from `MainDialog` and from `SecondDialog`.

Comment: I've just initialized `FirstDialog` with two different IDs in `MainDialog`. When calling from `MainDialog` it will be called with ID - `$"{nameof(MainDialog)}.first"` using `BeginDialogAsync` and when calling from `SecondDialog`,  it will be called with ID - `$"{nameof(SecondDialog)}.firstFromSecond"`. Based on the Dialog Id, received by `FirstDialog`, two different` waterfall` have been designed. No code has to be re-written here.